# Receiving "End of file" while streaming RTSP on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm using ffmpeg library to stream RTSP from an IP camera in the local network. The streaming is working fine with the code.

The only problem is that the stream seems to stop after some time. On further debugging I found out that I'm receiving an "End of file" and thats why the loop is breaking.

```
while(!playerShouldStop)// && (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &pkt1)>=0))
    {
            int ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &pkt1);
            NSLog(@"av read frame returned = %s",av_err2str(ret));
            if(ret >= 0)
            {
                // process video
            }
            else 
               break;
    }
```

Logs says

> av read frame returned = End of file

I downloaded Wireshark to check what RTSP packets I'm getting but no help there.

[image]

**First** of all is it normal to receive EOF in a live stream (which is not supposed to end).

**Secondly**, calling **`av_read_frame()`** again and again is not helping either, but when I restart the entire method ( right from **`avformat_open_input`** ) then it works. Just that the streaming isn't smooth and comes to a pause every now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...it seems to be working without EOF when i open the stream with AVDictionary options.

```
AVDictionary *opts = 0;
int ret = av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);

// Open video file and read header information into pFormatCtx
        if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, &opts) != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error opening video file.");
            return;
        }

        av_dict_free(&opts);
```

Still, any proper explanation to this would be helpful.

Comment: using the dictionary like this is specifying to open the stream using tcp, if you don't make this entry ffmpeg will first attempt to open the stream using UDP as the transport , upon failing it will try TCP. my guess is the EOF you see is from the first failure.

Comment: @MichelleCannon..I restart the connection after the first EOF and still after sometime I received EOF. And the connection fails mid way of streaming. (not like the streaming didn't begin at all)

Comment: well all your code is doing above is forcing tcp over udp. its possible the streams your reading are available with both protocols, but the UDP one has issues.

Comment: I've tried with 2 cameras...was facing the same problem with both of them..I haven't found any other plausible explanation for this

Comment: hmm... this is weird I get the EOF when I use tcp... If I do not set the options I do not get the EOF.... am I correct in understanding that your experience is exactly opposite?

Answer (score 0):

I have met same question about av_read_frame return EOF(End Of File) while decoding realtime stream. Finanlly I found that when this problem appears. It's Because I set the AVFormatCtx.interrupt_callback.callback, and the number of timeout is too small(this call back can prevent av_read_frame() blocking). So When The callback return, av_read_frame() return EOF. Hope this question I met may help you.